# Progress bar to indicate file is being saved doesn't go away

Tags: excel, vba, document-classification

I have an Excel macro that opens a workbook, does some operations, saves and closes it. It worked for the last 2 years.

TITUS was installed on my work machine and because of this, I have to choose a document classification manually every time code tries to save the workbook.

As a workaround, I use `Application.EnableEvents = False` before save and close statements. After that, the macro sometimes stops at save bar like shown in this image: [Save bar](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/152104)

The workbook is saved but the save bar doesn't close and halts the macro from opening any other workbooks. This occurs randomly for random workbooks. For example, when workbook 3 had this issue, if I run the macro on workbook 3 again, it might or might not cause the trouble.

Comment: Have you tried putting `Application.EnableEvents = True` after save events?

Comment: Tried that @TomJohnRiddle it's not working. I even tried disabling display alerts. None worked